# How to hide backgroud image on small devices?

Tags: tailwind-css

In tailwindcss: 2.2 layout I have image defined in backgroud

```
<div class="absolute top-0 w-full h-full bg-gray-900" style="background-image: url(./assets/img/register_bg_2.png); background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"
></div>
```

and I  to hide this backgroud image on small devices. I know how to use

```
 xs:hidden
```

But in this case all div will be hidden, nut image. How can I do it without splitting into 2 divs ?

**UPDATED PART :**

I modified tailwind.config.js and added definition :

```
module.exports = {
    purge: {
        options: {
            safelist: [...ta_gallery_safelist],
        },
    },
    theme: {

        extend: {

            backgroundImage: theme => ({
                'test-device-sm': "url('/img/test-device/sm.png')",
                'test-device-md': "url('/img/test-device/md.png')",
                'test-device-lg': "url('/img/test-device/lg.png')",
                'test-device-xl': "url('/img/test-device/exlg.png')",
                // 'personal_page_container_wrapper_bg_image': "url('/img/register_bg_2.png');  background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;",
                'personal_page_container_wrapper_bg_image': "url('/img/register_bg_2.png')",

            }),
```

but adding personal_page_container_wrapper_bg_image to my divs I do not see any background
image or invalid path error in the console...
classes test-device-... I use to show current device and it work ok...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `xs:hidden` will hide the element above `xs` screen size, not below. You can read about it [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design).

You can hide background-image by setting it to `none`. So for your case, you could write your own css like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: yourvalue) {
  yourselector {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
```

or to use tailwind syntax, you could use something like this:

```css
@screen xs {
  yourselector {
    background-image: url(./assets/img/register_bg_2.png); 
    background-size: 100%;
    @apply bg-no-repeat;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```
class='bg-opacity-0 xs:bg-opacity-100'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the logical way is to add your background image by editing the theme.backgroundImage section of your tailwind.config.js file:

```
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        backgroundImage: {
+         'bg-header': "url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')",
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you can do something like:

```
<div class="absolute top-0 w-full h-full bg-gray-900 bg-none sm:bg-header"
```

> 

If you are not familiar with how "tailwind.config.js" works, [read this section](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#create-your-configuration-file), it's the most practical way to customize tailwindcss.

Comment: please review UPDATED PART

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this code below

```
<div className={`sm:bg-[url('/src/assets/background.jpeg')] bg-cover bg-no-repeat h-screen`}>
```

add `sm` to specify minimum width.
i'm using `"tailwindcss": "^3.4.0"`

Answer (score 0):

You can define your background image css class name in `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        hero: "url('/hero.webp')",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Then show it in large devices and hide it on smaller devices by applying these class names:

```
<div className="bg-none sm:bg-hero">...</div>
```